# How to use VFL constraint to custom cell in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

|I have a TableView (alertTableView) in my viewcontroller with a custom UITableViewCell (cell). To this UITableViewCell i want to set some constraints;

- cell needs to resize horizontally to match the width of the screen and has a
  spacing of 50pts. left and right.
- height of the cell is 10pts
- between the cells i want to have a small space of 2 points vertically.

To do this i used VFL to add the constraints, but the constraints are not set/respected. I assume that i have to set the constraints on the AlertTableView and not on view. Tried it anyway, but as expected by myself this did not make a difference.

```
    /*
        VFL constraints Table View Cell
    */
    let cell:ReportTableviewCell = self.alertTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ReportTableviewCell
    cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    alertTableView.addSubview(cell)
    let cellDictionary = ["ReportTableviewCell": cell]

    alertTableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(50)-[ReportTableviewCell]-(50)-|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:  cellDictionary))
    alertTableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[ReportTableviewCell(cellHeight)]-(cellVSpacing)-|",options: [], metrics: ["cellHeight" : 40, "cellVSpacing" : 2], views:  cellDictionary))
```

What's done wrong ?

== new revision of the example ==

```
    // Register ReportCell
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ReportCell", bundle: nil)
    alertTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    /*
        VFL constraints Table View Cell
    */
    let cell:ReportTableviewCell = self.alertTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ReportTableviewCell

    cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    alertTableView.addSubview(cell)

    var cellAllConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    let cellDictionary = ["ReportTableviewCell": cell,
                          "reportCellDateTime": cell.reportCellDateTimeOutlet]

    let cellHorizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-50-[ReportTableviewCell]-50-|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:  cellDictionary)
    let cellVerticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[ReportTableviewCell(cellHeight)]-(cellVSpacing)-|",options: [], metrics: ["cellHeight" : 10, "cellVSpacing" : 2], views:  cellDictionary)        
    cellAllConstraints += cellHorizontalConstraints        
    cellAllConstraints += cellVerticalConstraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(cellAllConstraints)


    // set constraint on UILabel reportCellDateTimeOutlet in cell ReportCell        
    cellAllConstraints.removeAll()        
    let dateTimeHorizontalConstrains = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-50-[reportCellDateTime]-|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:  cellDictionary)
    cellAllConstraints += dateTimeHorizontalConstrains
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(cellAllConstraints)
```

when erroneously adding a cell or UILabel to an UITableView like `alertTableView.addSubview(cell.reportCellDateTimeOutlet)` a hidden cell is added to the UITableView which becomes visible when dragging down the top cell. This was wrong as pointed out by bsmith11.

[image]

Still when using a custom cell in a UITableView and setting the constraints for a specific UILabel in that cell, the constraints are not affected.

```
    let cell:ReportTableviewCell = self.alertTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ReportTableviewCell
    var cellAllConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    let cellDictionary = [
                                  "reportCellDateTime": cell.reportCellDateTimeOutlet,
                                  "reportCellViewedIndicator" : cell.reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet,
        "reportCellDescription" : cell.reportCellDescriptionOutlet ]
    cell.reportCellDateTimeOutlet.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let dateTimeHorizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-50-[reportCellDateTime(300)]-|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:  cellDictionary)
    cellAllConstraints += dateTimeHorizontalConstraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(cellAllConstraints)
```

As suggested by bsmith11 i moved the code from the ViewController to the class extending the UITableViewCell. Also changed the programmatically application of constraints from VFL to Layout anchors. Does not work for me unfortunately.

```
class ReportTableviewCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var reportCell: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()

      // Internal border
      self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 166/255, blue: 35/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
      self.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
      self.layer.masksToBounds = true
      self.layer.borderWidth = 4.0

      reportCell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(reportCell.bottomAnchor, constant: 10)
      reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(reportCell.rightAnchor, constant:-10)
      reportCellDescriptionOutlet.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      reportCellDescriptionOutlet.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(reportCell.leftAnchor, constant: 10).active = true                  reportCellDescriptionOutlet.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(reportCell.rightAnchor, constant: 10).active = true

      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
  "H:|-(50)- ...
```

instead of

```
   "H:-(50)-| ...
```

Comment: I indeed meant that, fixed it in the question. Does not fix the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `UITableView` incorrectly.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

You should be settings constraints on subviews inside of your `UITableViewCell` subclass. The `UITableView` will handle layout of the actual cells.

Comment: I understand that i have to set constraints on subviews inside a *UITableViewCell* subclass when need to set constraints on these subviews. But i need to set the constraints on the *UITableViewCell* in the *UITableView*. 

I have updated the question with a modified version of the example and added a constraint on the UILabel in the cell. This also does not seem to work.

Comment: You should never be manually adding a `UITableViewCell` as a subview to a `UITableView` or manually setting constraints between the two. Please read the Apple documentation on proper `UITableView` usage.

Comment: I have gone through the apple docs, went through one of Ray Wenderlichs tutorials again.
(https://www.raywenderlich.com/110393/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial) But still have no idea what i am doing wrong here. Added a new simple snippet.

Comment: In your current implementation, your constraints are getting added each time the cell is reused. Try adding your constraints inside of your `UITableViewCell` subclass in `awakeFromNib()`, this way your constraints only get added one time at cell creation. Also make sure to only add subviews to `.contentView` of your `UITableViewCell` subclass.

I would also suggest not using VFL if your app supports only iOS 9. Instead use the new layout anchor API introduced in iOS 9 as they are much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: i expected that when adding my constrains to the viewDidLoad in the ViewController the constraints would be added to the cell once. When moving the constraints to the awakeFromNib of the cell's class file i can see that the constraint is set (repeated) for each cell instance. Also when moving the code to the awakeFromNib, the constraints do still not become effective.

Put the whole project on GitHub; https://github.com/petervannes/homecaremonitor

Will try to do some more reading to get a better understanding if the NSLayoutAnchor class

Comment: Tried to make the changes you suggested. Found out that i needed to add an outlet for the cell itself. Tried earlier to use VFL in the awakeFormNib but it faile because it could not find a parent view for the UILabels, now understand why..
I am trying to get a better understanding of the new layout anchor API's, but most examples are not very exhaustive or complete. Any suggestions for (commercial) documentation focussed on the new layout anchors?
Added the new code using the layout anchors, but although no constraint warnings are shown, the constraint seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have been able to set constraints. As suggested by @bsmith11 i switched to NSConstraints in favour of VFL. Also moved the programmatically defined constraints from the ViewController to the class extending the UITableViewCell class.

```
@IBOutlet weak var reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var reportCell: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    reportCell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // viewed Indicator constraints
    let viewedIndicatorConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.rightAnchor, constant: -3),
        reportCellViewedIndicatorOutlet.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomAnchor, constant: -3)

    ]

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(viewedIndicatorConstraints)
```